# Como ativar o Java EE no Apache Netbeans IDE 10

Tags: java, java-ee, netbeans

Eu baixei a versão final do Apache Netbeans 10.0 no [site oficial](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html), no entanto o Java EE não vem ativado, eu vou para o próprio Plugin IDE, mas a opção de download não aparece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vá em instalar plugins, aba installed (ou instalados), botão direito em Java Web and EE e escolha Check All. Depois clique no botão active (ou ativar).